# Javascript: Putting a looping jQuery animation inside a js function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I want to nest a looping jQuery animation function inside a js function, and I can't figure out how to do it.

I have an audio file that plays when a div is clicked (and pauses if the div is clicked again), and at the same time the div text changes from a play symbol to a pause symbol. I want to animate another div while the music is playing, and stop the animation when the music is paused.

Here is my audio function code:

```
function play() {
    var audio = document.getElementById('whatchaDoin');

    if (audio.paused) {
        audio.play();
        document.getElementById('playButton').innerHTML = '\u2016';

    } else {
        audio.pause();
        document.getElementById('playButton').innerHTML = '\u25BA';
    }
}
```

And here's my animation:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function animateBox() {
        $('#greenBox').animate({
            'margin-top': '20px',
            'height': '150px',
            'width': '150px'
        }, 195).animate({
            'margin-top': '30px',
            'height': '140px',
            'width': '140px'
        }, 390, animateBox);
    }
    animateBox();
});
```

I can't seem to find a way to put them together without breaking the play function. 
Thanks for any help you can give me!

Comment: Define "breaking the play function". Also, why can't you just put the `animateBox()` inside of your `play` function? Unless I misunderstand.

Comment: Hi Matt: I mean that the play function stops working, when I add the animateBox function to it -- I have done it wrong several different ways; I don't know how to do it properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work. I haven't tried it with an audio object, but the animation loop should be correct. Here is a jsFiddle without audio object:
https://jsfiddle.net/5fwdcq37/1/

The code below should be it with audio, important to know that when you stop an animation in jquery and you set the "jumpToEnd" flag to `true` it will fire the complete function. In your example before that would then again start the animation loop, so you would never be able to stop it. Therefore you need to add an additional variable `loop` to check if it is supposed to loop:

```
function play() {
    var audio = document.getElementById('whatchaDoin');

    if (audio.paused) {
        audio.play();
        document.getElementById('playButton').innerHTML = '\u2016';
        startAnimation();

    } else {
        audio.pause();
        document.getElementById('playButton').innerHTML = '\u25BA';
        stopAnimation();
    }
}

var loop = false;
function startAnimation(){
   loop = true;
   $('#greenBox').animate({
            'margin-top': '20px',
            'height': '150px',
            'width': '150px'
        }, 195).animate({
            'margin-top': '30px',
            'height': '140px',
            'width': '140px'
        }, 390, function(){ if(loop){ startAnimation(); } });
}

function stopAnimation(){
  loop = false;
  $('#greenBox').stop( true, true );
}

$( "#playButton" ).click( play );
```

Comment: Thanks, Bjorn -- but it is not working for me on my page. The audio does not play, and the animation does not start. See here: http://carolineingles.com/ Do you know what the problem could be?

Comment: Yes, you are firing `play()` twice, once on html tag `onClick` and the other time with `$( "#playButton" ).click( play )` from my code. Remove one of them. 
Question, are you familiar with the Developer Tools in your browser?

Comment: That was it! It works! I was not aware of Developer Tools, but I will check them out. Thanks again for helping me!

Comment: Your'e welcome. You definately have to check them out. You don't really want to live without them. Yuo can check if you sorces are loaded properly, if your scripts causes errors and even check if a particular function is called (and with which parameters ).